# How to add Geocoding to eclipse?

Tags: java, google-maps, jsp

I'm working on java application in eclipse. And need to use geocoding API. But can not find a page with instructions to learn how to use it in eclipse without using geolocation stuff.

Comment: There's no need eclipse documentation. Geocoding is just a Google Webservice you send a request and you receive a JSON response. All details here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Viewports

Comment: I see....you are right. I just got it working....thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty nice Java Client Library for Google Maps Web Services on GitHub. You can have a look at

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java